# Spock's @Unroll vs. @Stepwise

Tags: spock

Say I have a `Specification` with a single `@Unroll` test in it

```groovy
class MySpec extends Specification {

  @Unroll
  def "some test, executed n times, with n>1"() {
    // when, then, where
  }
}
```

Would it be redundant to annotate `MySpec` to be executed `@Stepwise`? Is this treated as one test (executed n times in a row) or as n tests (executed in parallel)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Stepwise` ensures that all test methods run in the order shown in the source file.

`@Unroll` is useful for parameterized tests because it forces all test scenarios in a single test method to be reported as individual test runs.

So in your case `@Stepwise` is redundant and all *unrolled* tests are executed in the order as specified in the `where` clause.

Generally in Spock 1.x all tests are executed *in row* and even those unrolled from `where` clause. Parallelism is planned for Spock 2.0 - as you can see here https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/157